# Check if user has access to operation in Yii RBAC

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I've implemented basic RBAC functionality in my application using Yii. There are roles, tasks and operations set up and working fine.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following: on user login, check if the user is privileged to log in to this certain area of my application. There's a operation assigned to this particular task. The problem, however, is that the preferred method of checking is the user is permitted to use a operation is *CWebUser::checkAccess*, which isn't available in the login as the Yii login workflow goes like this:

- The user provides information needed for authentication.
- An identity instance is created with the user-provided information.
- Call
  IUserIdentity::authenticate to check if the identity is valid.
- If
  valid, call CWebUser::login to login the user, and Redirect the user
  browser to returnUrl.
- If not valid, retrieve the error code or
  message from the identity instance and display it.

[taken from here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#checkAccess-detail)

The CWebUser instance available globally via *Yii::app()->user* is not propagated while in the login state, (list items two and three) which makes perfect sense to me. However, in order to call checkAccess I'd need a CWebUser instance. CAuthManager doesn't seem to provide the functionality I need as it is (there's no method for checking if a user has a certain atomic permission (operation) or list all of them).
In my example, the operation needed is mostly always assigned in conjunction with a role, but who knows - somebody might just have access to this one operation of logging in, which is a case I want to cover.

**thanks a lot!**

Comment: `CAuthManager` has checkAccess method. That checks rights

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#checkAccess-detail

Comment: Great - it worked! Would you mind to post that as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: You're welcome. I do it right now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAuthManager` has already a `checkAccess` method, which performs what you need. For more information you can check Yii's official documents:

[IAuthManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#checkAccess-detail)